# Java server socket connecting to HTML client

Tags: java, html, sockets

Is it possible to connect a java server, sending picture data with sockets, to an HTML page, that can then render those pictures on screen?

It would also be helpful to know how to send a response from the HTML page back to the java server. (If for example, someone clicked their mouse on the page)

Comment: HTML itself is just static content. You need server side code (php, C#, tons of other choices) to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Welcome to S.O James. This is certainly doable in Java. It might be worth taking a look at [Java RMI](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

import java.util.Properties;

class SimpleMail1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        System.out.println("Sending mail...");
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.mymailserver.com");
        props.setProperty("mail.user", "myuser");
        props.setProperty("mail.password", "mypwd");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);
        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        message.setSubject("HTML  mail with images");
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("me@sender.com"));
        message.setContent
          ("<h1>This is a test</h1>" 
           + "<img src=\"http://www.rgagnon.com/images/jht.gif\">", 
           "text/html");
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
             new InternetAddress("you@receiver.com"));

        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(message,
            message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Would the code be able to accept a connection from the client, and or accept a data response back from the site?